# Series involving gamma functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function

How do we represent the summation in the form of elementary functions??

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^n \Gamma(n+a)}{n! \Gamma(n+b)}}
$$

Comment: are there any assumptions on $a,b$?

Comment: The assumptions are $$ a,b > 0 \ \ \  and \ \ \  a>b $$ . 

Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the definition:
$$\Gamma(n+a)=(a)_n\Gamma(a)$$
where $(a)_n$ is the Pochhammer symbol.

So
$$$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^n \Gamma(n+a)}{n! \Gamma(n+b)}}=\frac{\Gamma(a)}{\Gamma(b)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(a)_nx^n }{(b)_n n!}}=\frac{\Gamma (a) \,}{\Gamma (b)}\, _1F_1(a;b;x)$$
where $_1F_1(a;b;x)$ is confluent hypergeometric function.

Comment: Thanks Caran-d'Ache.

I think your answer already supports the assumptions I mentioned.